# unity container resolving covariance

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a model based on Entities, and all entities inherit from BaseEntity

```
public class BaseEntity{}
public class ClientEntity:BaseEntity{}
public class SpecialClientEntity:ClientEntity{}
public class ProductEntity:BaseEntity{}
public class SpecialProductEntity:ProductEntity{}
```

And I this interface

```
public interface IValidationRule<out T>
{
    bool IsValid(object parameter);
}
```

what I tried to make is to register the validation Rules, for example

```
public class BaseValidationRule:IValidationRule<BaseEntity>{}
public class ClientValidationRule:IValidationRule<ClientEntity>{}
public class SpecialClientValidationRule:IValidationRule<SpecialClientEntity>{}


public class ProductValidationRule:IValidationRule<ProductEntity>{}
public class SpecialProductValidationRule:IValidationRule<SpecialProductEntity>{}
```

and I want this result

```
foreach (var foo in container.ResolveAll<IValidationRule<SpecialClientEntity>>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
```

and get as result the 3 first validation Rules and not the 2 last validation rules, how can I register it? instead of registering it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with unity but This might work

```
 container.ResolveAll(typeof(IValidationRule<>));
```

also the below approach is also an option

```
public interface IValidationRule{
    bool IsValid(object parameter);
}

public interface IValidationRule<out T> : IValidationRule
{
}

var foo in container.ResolveAll<IValidationRule>();
```

---

for registering unity services

```
RegisterType(typeof(IValidationRule<BaseEntity>), typeof(BaseValidationRule));
RegisterType(typeof(IValidationRule<ClientEntity>), typeof(ClientValidationRule),  "Name-1");
RegisterType(typeof(IValidationRule<SpecialClientEntity>), typeof(SpecialClientValidationRule), "Name-2");
RegisterType(typeof(IValidationRule<ProductEntity>), typeof(ProductValidationRule), "Name-3");
RegisterType(typeof(IValidationRule<SpecialProductEntity>), typeof(SpecialProductValiationRule), "Name-4");
```

---

*and get as result the 3 first validation Rules and not the 2 last validation rules, how can I register it? instead of registering it multiple times.*

there must be something which seperated these three from others. This can be interface.

After that you can use reflection to get types which belongs to that specific interface

Example for reflection:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterface(typeof(ISeperatorInterface<>).Name) != null && mytype.IsClass)
```

returns you types as Type. Then you can resolve them by

```
.Resolve(<myType>);

var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterface(typeof(ISeperatorInterface<>).Name) != null && mytype.IsClass);

foreach (var type in types)
    container.Resolve(type);
```

Comment: This works im my example, but it doesn't work in the complete idea, I'll complete the example to show what I imagine

Comment: Thanks, I created a method that uses something similiar, but I need to use that extension method when the registration is with an interface that has in or out, but what I really wanted was something more transparent to use as a default in the project